# OKTA microservice authentication

Tags: microservices, okta, okta-signin-widget

I've a OKTA project which `OIDC - SPA`.

We have implemented micro service architecture in the BE so there are multiple services which accept auth-token from users which are minted by above SPA application. Now, I want to enable microservice communication and want to have some kind of authenticaion between them.

Below is what I want to achieve:
[image: sever-side-com]

Inorder to acheive this I need to create an application with type `Web Application` because I need `clientId` and `secret` inorder to generate a serverside token.

I currently have a `SPA`, here are my options:

1. Create new application with type `Web Application` and use `SPA` on `FE` and `WA` on `BE`.
2. Get rid of `SPA` and use `WA` on both `FE` and `BE`.

What are the consequences of either approaches?

Comment: Are you talking about MS talking to MS or like in diagram your client talking to MS?

Comment: @PhilippGrigoryev, Client is a MS. So yes, MS talking to MS.

Comment: I'd create multiple clients in Okta (client credentials), each one for its own MS. Web app should stay the same as it was